# conflicting options errors

Tags: biblatex

I have in the preamble:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amstext,amsmath,latexsym,mathtools}
\usepackage[italian,british]{babel}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[utf8,latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}        
\usepackage{cmbright}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[style=authoryearcomp,firstinits=true,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{trybib.bib}

\nocite{*}
```

I get these two errors:

```
conflicting options
'firstinits' conflicts with'uniquename=true'
```

and

```
Data encoding is 'latin1'
Use backend=bibtex8 or backend=biber
```

I need all these packages, how can I fix these errors?

Comment: i dont think you can use two input encoding latin1 and utf8. \usepackage[style=authoryearcomp,firstinits=true,maxcitenames=2,maxbibnames=99]{} , there is closing square bracket ']' missing probably.

Comment: @texlearner A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) in comments as well as in posts.

Comment: @texlearner: Also, `inputenc` is for the input encoding (of your .tex file), `fontenc` would be for the font encoding.

Comment: @texlearner I have the same problem if I use just either 'latin1' or 'utf8'. I have to fix the options; I am trying to know how

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I just had to do some sorting and cleaning up,
the following questions are probably relevant for you:

- [How to use biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26516/how-to-use-biber)
- [biber .bcf file extension](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44040/biblatex-biber-texmaker-miktex)
- [utf8 or latin1 input encoding?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/utf8-or-latin1-encoding-german)
- [change encoding of files](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19427/how-do-i-change-the-encoding-of-my-files)
- [Which packages to load after hyperref?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before)
- [What packages do people load by default?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)
- [lmodern vs. cm-super](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/latin-modern-vs-cm-super)
- [font packages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/59403/what-font-packages-are-installed-in-tex-live)

After that, I only had to do what `biblatex` was suggesting.
The following should compile without warnings/errors.
Please note the comments.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amstext,amsmath,latexsym,mathtools}  % do you really need all?
\usepackage{pdfpages}  % you had that package twice
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  % use utf8 for all files
\usepackage[italian,british]{babel}   
\usepackage{cmbright}  % needs the cm-super package to be installed
% \usepackage{lmodern}  % try this one instead of cm-bright + cm-super

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}     
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,  % run biber.exe instead of bibtex.exe
    style=authoryear-comp,
    firstinits=true,
    uniquename=init,  % this option is compatible with firstinits
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=99
]{biblatex}
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{last-first}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\mkbibbold{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage{hyperref}  % hyperref should usually be the last package
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true
}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet \cite{kastenholz}.
At vero utilisam \cite{bertram}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Yes without any errors, but the citation does not display! I am trying to get it right, then will tell you. Thank you

Comment: excuse me, should I compile with     bibtex filename.aux or     biber filename.aux?

Comment: `biber` actually operates on the `.bcf` file, so you should use that file extension or, even better, just use no file extension at all.