# How to use amssymb's \blackbox symbol

Tags: symbols, incompatibility, amssymb

I have following problem - I want to use `\blackbox` in my file, which is provided by `amssymb` package. I use the following packages: `babel`, `[T1]{fontenc}`, `[latin2]{inputenc}`, none of which allows `\blackbox`. As if I try to add `amssymb` to list of packages and then compile the file, an error occurs. Can anyone suggest some way to overcome this problem?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There exists a [comprehensive list of symbols in LaTeX](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf).
Alternatively you can try the [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) homepage.
According to both, there is no symbol called `\blackbox`.

But there is a symbol called `\blacksquare`, which might be an alternative here.
It is made available by the `amssymb` package.
The following MWE shows how to use that symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % font encoding
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding
\usepackage[english]{babel} % keyword translation and hyphenation
\usepackage{lmodern} % lmodern looks better than cm-super

%% ==================
\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
%\blackbox
Some text about a little black $\blacksquare$ square.
\begin{equation}
    3+4 = \blacksquare
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

PS: You can change the input encoding back to `latin2`, but `utf8` has only [advantages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1811/utf8-or-latin1-encoding-german).