# Need help making sure a given thesis template is in line with my uni's style requirements (margin, spacing, font, etc)

Tags: fonts, spacing, margins, footnotes

I'm still in the process of getting **Sunil Patel**'s [**Thesis Template.zip**](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Thesis-Template.zip) primed for writing. I've just overcome the [unicode trouble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103995/need-help-to-make-a-given-thesis-template-compatible-with-german-umlauts-erro) and now **need to make sure** the template's *in line* with my university's **style requirements**

- **Margin**: left 3 cm, on the right 2.5 cm, at the top 2.5 cm, bottom 2.5 cm
- **Spacing**: 1.5
- **Font size**: 12 pt
- **Font**: Times New Roman
- **Footnotes**: single-spaced and font size: 10 pt

***Where exactly*** do I need to make these changes (if changes are necessary at all)?

---

For instance, I [**grep**'ed](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (the [***.zip**'s contents](http://www.sunilpatel.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/Thesis-Template.zip)) for "**margin**" and got the following list:

> Chapters/Chapter1.tex
>
> lstpatch.sty
>
> Missing Packages/fancyhdr.sty
>
> Missing Packages/subfigure.sty
>
> Missing Packages/caption.sty
>
> Missing Packages/natbib.sty
>
> Missing Packages/listings.sty
>
> Missing Packages/vmargin.sty
>
> Thesis.cls

plus some log-files.

---

**PS**: If you happen to know of an **alternative template** which looks similar to Sunil's and which might be (even more) beginner-friendly, plz do let me know.

Comment: Could you please post a link to the source files themselves, as opposed to a link to .zip that allegedly contains them? I'm wary of opening untrusted .zip's.

Comment: @Jubobs http://www.wobzip.org/ might do the trick?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty You'ld increase your chances of getting _any_ help if you made it easier for others to find what they need.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen I'm new to TeX, I'm willing to learn; I'm trying to be as clear and "easy" as I can; plz let me know what more I can do apart from supplying a link to a hosted zip-file...? (*and* a link to service which will unzip the hosted zip-file on the fly)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty Providing hyperlinks to the packages in your question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not quite sure, if this breaks some uses of \footnotesize in other packages, but it works so far:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} %Font size set to 12pt
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry} %Margins set
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} %Linespacing to 150%
\usepackage{fontspec} %%%% Requires XeLaTeX, not LaTeX
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} %Set Times New Roman as the main font
\renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\fontsize{10pt}{10pt}\selectfont} %Sets the footnote in 10pt with single spacing
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-30]
foobar\footnote{\lipsum[31]}
\lipsum[32-40]
\end{document}
```

Attention: This uses the `fontspec` package, which requires `xelatex` or `lualatex` instead of `latex`. If you cannot use one of these engines, you have to find another way to use Times New Roman. The rest of the code is independant from that, imho.

BTW: If you use math in your document, you should also set the math fonts accordingly. For `xelatex` and `lualatex`, this can be achieved with the `unicode-math` package and the font XITS Math.

Comment: To use Times New Roman and regular `pdfTeX`, all you need to do is `\usepackage{mathptmx}`.  (On GNU/Linux, this will give you Nimbus Roman No9, which is a TNR clone.)